# passing argument value in another function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to use the arguments passed in one function in another function too.Can anyone help me if it is possible to do or not

```
 function getByID(UserID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/User/GetByID/" + UserID,
        type: "Get",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            debugger;
            $('#Username').val(result.Username);
            $('#Email').val(result.Email);
            $('#roleName').val(result.RoleID);
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    })
    return UserID;

};
```

i want to use "UserID argument in another function" like:

```
$('#modalEdit').on('click',function() {
    var objUpdate = {
        //UserID:i want here ,
        Username: $('#Username').val(),
        Email: $('#Email').val(),
        RoleID: $('#roleName').val()

    };
```

Below is the Html view of my table

```
<tbody>
            @if (!Model.Any())
            {
                <tr>
                No Data Availables
                </tr>
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, sn = i + 1 }))
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Data.UserID,new { @class="hiddenUser"})

                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.sn</td>
                        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.Username,new { @id="Username"})</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.Email, new { @id = "Email" })</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.RoleName, new { @id = "Role" })</td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" id="btnEdit" onclick="return getByID(@item.Data.UserID)" class="btn btn-primary fa fa-edit"
                             data-target="#editUser"
                            data-toggle="modal">Edit</button>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Where and how do you call the function `getById` from.

Comment: i called it from the button like <button onclick="return getByID(item.data)"></button> and that item.data is an userID i got from the row of the table

Comment: I dont see what the problem is. You can get the value in your `click` event function by accessing `$(this)` ie. if the button is in the row.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML structure of the button and table.

Comment: above i have edited my question

Comment: Where is the element `#modalEdit` in the HTML.

Comment: modal edit is in another view

Comment: @Html.Partial("_UpdateModalPartial") i included that view like given

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary fa fa-edit" id="modalEdit">Edit</button>

Answer (score 0):

Try setting another `data-` attribute in your button `btnEdit` to hold the userId.

```
data-info = "@item.Data.UserID"
```

In your click function

```
$('#modalEdit').on('click',function() {
  var userId = $("btnEdit").attr("data-info");
});
```